# MySQL SSL error: Unable to get private key

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, encryption, ssl

Getting an error while trying to enable encryption:

```
[ERROR] SSL error: Unable to get private key from '/etc/mysql/ssl/nginx.key'
[Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: Unable to get private key
```

/etc/mysql/conf.d/encrypt.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ssl/nginx.ca
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/ssl/nginx.crt
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/ssl/nginx.key
```

The key is generated like that:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout nginx.key -subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=Sacramento/O=MyOrg/OU=MyDev/CN=MyApp"
```

The openssl checks it fine.

I've tried to change permissions, owners, file names, moving to different directories, disabling SELinux (it's already disabled), looking at AppArmor logs (it doesn't block it), changing 'BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY' to 'BEGIN/END RSA PRIVATE KEY'.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, apparently just changing 'BEGIN PRIVATE KEY' to 'BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY' isn't enough.

It must be properly converted from PKCS#8 to PKCS#1 [Reference](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71271)

```
openssl rsa -in /etc/mysql/ssl/nginx.key -out ~/nginx.key.rsa
```

Comment: Why did I just search the Internet for an hour for this...thank you.

Comment: Mine needed this because it was originally generated by LetsEncrypt for my website. But Apache needed *no* conversion.

Comment: The above almost did the trick for me. I am using OpenSSL 3 and had to specify the -traditional option to get PKCS#1 output.

Answer (score 3):

As a consolidation of my false leads that helped others:

- POSIX mode bits and file owner: The mysql user must have read access to all SSL files via user or group privileges. This may mean `chown mysql *.pem` or adding ssl-private to mysql's groups. (https://serverfault.com/questions/417390/cannot-setup-mysql-ssl-unable-to-read-certificate)
- AppArmor can cut off file access. You need something like `/etc/mysql/**` in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin/mysqld`. Check `/var/log/kern.log` and consider `aa-complain /usr/sbin/mysqld` to get errors rather than denials.(https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?26,393495,393636#msg-393636)
- Malformatted file contents. SSL library is very bad at complaining accurately. Ensure the full key set works on, say, a web site.
- The file is missing entirely. Again, in the error message there is no distinction made.

Comment: By `mysql user`, you may include `any user that connects to the database`. For example, using Proftpd with `mod_sql`, the `proftpd` user couldn't read the `client-key.pem`, hence was sending a `2026 SSL connection error: Unable to get private key`. Allowing the `proftpd` user to read the file fixed it. Thanks for your answer which helped me find this out!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer not given by those above: There is a problem with the certificate itself, or the certificate chain, and not the private key.  In our case, the certificate file contained the intermediate certificates in the authentication chain. The presence of these additional certificates caused MySQL to report the "Unable to get private key" error. This was found to be the case in MariaDB 5.5.64.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error on MariaDB 10.3 when using an EC key. Switching to RSA solved the issue. (And 10.6 worked with EC also.)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.

But instead of converting the private key from PKCS#8 to #1, it was enough to change the owner of the `ssl` folder and its content (even though the rest of `/etc/mysql/` was owned by a different user):

```
chown mysql:mysql /etc/mysql/ssl/ -R
```

Found that solution [on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/950457/373224)